# Preventing injection: Using prepared statements and parameters in a function - syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I'm very new to PHP and I'm trying to learn about security measures such as preventing Injections. Below is my code. Basically I'm getting the error **"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1".** The data is still being sent into the database but this error makes me think the injection prevention isn't working. I'm not missing any `{` as I'm using Dreamweaver and it tells me if I am at least.

Also, to note, database connection line and the function is in a separate php file than the stuff in the $_POST code.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $databaseName);

if ($_POST) { 
  if(isset($_POST['register'])){
      registerUser(           //I'm calling the function here
      $_POST['username'],
      $_POST['user_password'],
      $_POST['user_fname'],
      $_POST['user_lname'],
      $_POST['email'],
      $_POST['phone'],
      $_POST['user_birthdate'],
      $_POST['user_address1'],
      $_POST['user_address2'],
      $_POST['user_city'],
      $_POST['user_postcode'], 
      $conn);
      } 
}


function registerUser(
  $username,
  $user_password,
  $user_fname, 
  $user_lname, 
  $email, 
  $phone, 
  $user_birthdate, 
  $user_address1, 
  $user_address2, 
  $user_city, 
  $user_postcode, 
  $conn){
    if($stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO fcusers (
        username, 
        user_password, 
        user_fname, 
        user_lname, 
        email, 
        phone, 
        user_birthdate, 
        user_address1, 
        user_address2, 
        user_city, 
        user_postcode) 
        VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)")){
            $stmt->bind_param("sssssssssss",
            $username,
            $user_password,
            $user_fname, 
            $user_lname, 
            $email, 
            $phone,             
            $user_birthdate, 
            $user_address1, 
            $user_address2, 
            $user_city, 
            $user_postcode);

            $sql = $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
        }
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    if($result){
       echo "CONGRATS";
     }
  }
```

Comment: Stop single-quoting your variables in `bind_param`. You're sending the literal strings `$username`, etc. You want to send the values, not the variable names. Also, don't try to store a phone number as an integer. It's not an integer; it's a string.

Comment: @EdCottrell Turns out I HAD removed the quotes from the $username etc. And I have just now turned the phone to a string. But i am still getting the same Syntax error.

Comment: Then what you have posted is either not your real code or not the SQL statement causing the error. There's no way to get that error from what you have here.

Comment: Actually, you have a more fundamental problem. You don't call `mysqli_query` if you are using a prepared statement. `$stmt->execute()` has already executed the query. And as Hudixt says below, you have the wrong number of `?` placeholders.

Comment: @EdCottrell, Oh so I have to have an extra `?` because of the value types?

And for that `mysqli_query`, is there a way for me to re-code so it shows that the data was sent? (To get that `CONGRATS` echo, if that makes sense).

Comment: No, you have to have another `?` because you need as many placeholders as you have values to bind. You're trying to bind 12 variables, but you have only 11 placeholders. The types are irrelevant. An equally big problem is that you're using `mysqli_query` improperly.

Comment: @EdCottrell, he has 11 columns, 11 placeholders, and 11 parameters.  He wouldn't get a syntax error if the number of placeholders didn't match the number of parameters.

Comment: @EdCottrell, thanks. I got rid of the `mysqli_query`.
I changed the following:
From: `$sql = $stmt->execute();` 

To: `$result = $stmt->execute();` 

And I got rid of: `$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql)`

Comment: @Devon Crud. You're right. That's what I get for trying to comment while using a mobile device - I counted a column twice.

Comment: @EdCottrell, happens.  You were right about the literal strings though.

Comment: @Tootally Yes, just go with Devon's answer. I was wrong about the number of parameters, but the use of mysqli_query is definitely a problem.

Answer (score 2):

The error generated is from your mysqli_query(), not the prepared statement.  The prepared statement is executed with `$sql = $stmt->execute()`.

With `mysqli_query($conn,$sql)`, you are running a query with the return value of `$stmt->execute()` which in this case is evaluated as 1 (boolean true) hence the error: **syntax to use near '1'**

You can run your condition on `$stmt->execute()`:

```
$result = $stmt->execute() or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

Comment: Thanks! I just figured out as I was refreshing this thread. I've edited a bit of my code. 

From:
`$sql = $stmt->execute();` 
To:
`$result = $stmt->execute();`

And I got rid of:
`$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql)`